# Should hyphenated compound words be permitted to break across lines?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, compounds, compound-adjectives, compound-words

When using a hyphenated compound word (i.e., a compound adjective, verb, or noun) in a document and the word splits across two lines due to it being at the end of a line, is it considered improper to split it across lines and should one instead force it to the next line with a non-breaking hyphen?

For example, the compound adjective *self-supporting*:

> A good mat for this purpose should have enough rigidity such that the mat is self‑
>       supporting

versus

> A good mat for this purpose should have enough rigidity such that the mat is
>       self‑supporting

In other words, should one use a non-breaking hyphen in compound words so that the reader does not mistake the word for not being compound (e.g., *selfsupporting*) and just broken at a syllable due to being at the end of the line?

Comment: I've seen a style guide recommending rather than censuring the practice. Note that 'self-supporting' is compound.

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable to every publication I've ever worked for, which includes about twenty magazine and several book publishers. Many do not permit a double break--for example, putting "self-support-" on one line and "ing" on the next. Many computers programs do permit this, however, and editors often go into a file to manually override such a break. This has nothing to do with content or meaning or the reader's understanding--it is simply an aesthetic preference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, at least according to the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/576/01/):

> For line breaks, divide already-hyphenated words only at the hyphen:
>
> mass-
> produced
> self-
> conscious

Comment: If I were introducing a new compound word, I might want to avoid breaking it at all the first few times.

Comment: In Portuguese, we repeat the hyphen on the next line as well to make it clearer, resulting in (where `/` is the line break) `mass-/-produced` or `self-/-conscious`.  Is that ever used in English?

Comment: I've never seen hyphen doubling (having one copy at the end of line and another at the start of next line) in English nor Finnish (then languages I'm very familiar with). I know that Swedish doubles some letters in some cases. For example, Swedish word "tuggummi" (chewing gum) is hyphenated as "tugg- gummi" when hyphenated on separate lines. I think rules for hyphenation of any given language are a result of local historical decisions and we don't have international standards how hyphenation should work. I consider hyphenation similar to collation order – do not try to apply any logic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm British educated, and we were taught this for line-end compounds:

self
-conscious

mass
-produced

IOW, the hyphen went to the next line.